# What is a node group in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

According to documentation node group is an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group and associated Amazon EC2 instances that are managed by AWS for an Amazon EKS cluster.

Still, I'm confused, what is the purpose and objective of a node group as to why it exists? It seems like node group doesn't exist on kubernetes and only on eks.